# Odoo 10 - Customize mail template

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I see that email templates have the following footer:

"Powered by Odoo"

How can I remove that in the templates?

Thanks,

Comment: Which template you using?

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings -> email -> templates
select the template , edit

or you can code to remove the template by overriding or inheriting the template you need. 
if you need full branding options, this can be achieved by the addon in odoo community [here](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/odoo-debrand/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can take full control over mail templates if you want to develop custom XML views.

I am working in Odoo 16.0. I can't speak for older versions of Odoo, because I'm new, but here's what I know about Odoo 16.0.

Emails sent from odoo get wrapped in a "layout" template. The layout templates are located in "addons/mail/data/mail_templates_email_layouts.xml"

1. Create a new module and call it something like "your-custom-email-layouts".
2. Create the file: "your-custom-email-layouts/views/templates.xml"
3. Copy the entire contents of the the built-in
   mail_templates_email_layouts.xml into your own templates.xml file.
4. In your new file modify the template as you need. You can delete the
   Powered by Odoo text as you want.
5. In **manifest**.py, make sure to add a link to
   "your-custom-email-layouts/views/templates.xml" in the "data" array.
6. Install and activate your module. Your own xml templates will
   override the built-in mail templates.

Done!

NOTE: Odoo 'mail' module **manifest**.py specifies a "sequence" line.  All modules that specify a sequence line should load first.  Then all modules *without* a sequence line get loaded. Thus as long as your module doesn't have a sequence, it should load *after* the built-in mail module, which is what allows your own mail layout templates to override/replace the built-in ones.